# Can I force the use of the 'using' statement for instances of my IDisposable class?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, idisposable, using-statement

If my class (which in this case, takes care of database connections) implements `IDisposable`, is there a way I can force the use of of the *using statement* when instantiating my class? Or perhaps produce a compiler warning if this wasn't done?

eg:

```
MyDAL = new MyDal(); // Warns or errors
using (MyDAL = new MyDAL()) // Does not warn or error
```

Comment: I could never be 100% sure that there is no current or potential future use of my class that wouldn't necessarily fit the `using` pattern. How are you so sure?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I think it's more a case of communicating to the user that "this tool was not intended for this purpose" rather than "it is impossible to use this tool for this purpose".

Comment: I'd have to agree with Damien, the using statement is not the only way to correctly Dispose an instance of an object.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: To put it another way, it's like overridability. How can you be *so sure* that most methods in classes that inherit from yours don't need to override your methods by default? Obviously Java would agree with you there that you can't be so sure, but C# would disagree. It's blacklisting vs. whitelisting basically.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no language level support for this.

However, you may find that tools such as FxCop or ReSharper can warn about it. (You'd need to work out how to integrate that into your workflow.)

Answer (score 3):

Not at compile time, but you can make the finalizer throw an exception in debug mode.
That should tell you when the object wasn't disposed properly during debugging.

Comment: How can I detect that though?

Comment: @NickG: If it throws an exception then it wasn't disposed, simple as that.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - nothing is throwing an exception currently.

Comment: @NickG: No, what I'm saying is that *you* should add a **finalizer** that throws an exception if the object isn't disposed. Obviously that's not the case right now, I'm saying you should add that code.

Comment: You mean like this?

  `~SqlDataStore() {
   Dispose();

   #if DEBUG
   Debug.Fail("Dispose was not called on SqlDataStore.");
   #endif
  }`

Comment: @NickG: Almost, but you forgot to check if `Dispose` was previously called. You might need an additional variable to keep track of that.

Comment: @NickG Here is an example: `class MyDAL : IDisposable { bool hasBeenProperlyDisposed; public void Dispose() { DoTheDisposeStuff(); } void DoTheDisposeStuff() { /* your clean-up code here */ hasBeenProperlyDisposed = true; GC.SuppressFinalize(this); } ~MyDAL() { if (hasBeenProperlyDisposed) { return; } DoTheDisposeStuff(); throw new InvalidOperationException("The Dispose method was not called before this instance became garbage! Did someone forget to use the using statement?"); }`

Comment: For some reason when my run my code, the breakpoint in my destructor is not hit... I'll need to solve that first.

Comment: @NickG: It's only guaranteed to get hit sometime before the program has terminated (not immediately), and it won't get executed if you abort the program from within the debugger. It has to die a natural death (i.e., `Main` should return).

Comment: @NickG You never know when (or if) the garbage collector will do a collect that schedules that your finalizer (destructor) must be run, and later runs it.

Comment: In practice, it seems the destructor is called after the page lifecycle, so I never get to see the exception (the w3wp.exe worker process simply crashes in the background).

Answer (score 3):

If you're that certain that the only valid use case is within a `using` statement then you need to take control of that yourself.

Make your constructor(s) `private`, then have `static` method(s) that accept any required constructor parameters and a lambda/delegate, something like (assuming no constructor parameters):

```
public static void UseMyDal(Action<MyDal> actions){
   using(var dal = new MyDal())
   {
      actions(dal);
   }
}
```

(If you're feeling generous, you might also provide generic overloads that accept a `Func<MyDal,T>` instead so that callers can retrieve a value:

```
public static T UseMyDal<T>(Func<MyDal,T> actions){
   using(var dal = new MyDal())
   {
      return actions(dal);
   }
}
```

Comment: Love the extra idea here of a implementing a generic, and including return value.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach just moves the "using" problem elsewhere. It effective means the scope is restricted to a single line of code. I'd then have to manually dispose of the DAL further down which defeats the point of forcing "using".

Comment: @NickG - A `Func<>` or `Action<>` can be far more than a "single line of code" - it can be as much arbitrary code as you want to execute.

Comment: @NickG - indeed, if you choose to provide your `Action` to `UseMyDal` as an inline multi-line function, the function call will closely resemble a `using` statement, outside of it terminating with a `});` rather than a `}`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, there's no way to prevent the creation of an object that won't get disposed, unless you don't allow outside code to create an object, and all of the methods which do create the object dispose it before returning.  If methods which create objects must return while those objects are "live", the best you can do is have code raise an alarm when it knows that objects should have been disposed, but haven't been.  While that can be done in a destructor, a somewhat nicer approach may be to have the disposable objects register themselves with a "cleanup guard" when they are created, and unregister when they are disposed, and then have the program notify the cleanup guard when everything should be cleaned up.

An advantage of this approach is that unlike a finalizer, the cleanup guard would be running in a well-defined threading context, and so it would be in a much better position to sound an alarm.  Further, if your main thread code was something like:

```
void MainThreadProc(paramType param)
{
  CleanupGuard.RunGuardedCode(RealMainThreadProc, param);
}
```

then the `RunGuardedCode` could create the cleanup guardian, pass it to `RealMainThreadProc` along with `param`, and then notify it after `RealMainThreadProc` returns.  If that was the only public way to create a cleanup guardian, then any code which received a cleanup guardian could be sure it was running within such a block.

Answer (score -3):

yes we can, Please see example.

```
class test : IDisposable
{
    public void test()
    {
        using (test testobj = new test())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you implemented `public void Dispose()` this still wouldn't even compile. And this just also doesn't answer the question.